# The Orange in Crispy Orange Beef

Tags: chinese-cuisine

Every time I try to make crispy orange beef, I try to integrate orange(juice, concentrate, zest) so that orange flavor stands out, but it never does.

Does the orange in crispy orange beef refer to it as a garnish only?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the orange into the glaze? That's what I would do. What ingredients are you using?

Comment: I'm adding rice wine vinegar(1/3 cup) with soy sauce(3 tbs) and oyster sauce(2 tbs) and sugar(1/3 cup) and orange concentrate(3 tbs).

Comment: That seems like a of vinegar, actually it seems like a lot of liquid in general, almost a full cup of liquid. I like rice wine vinegar for Asian glazes. It brightens them up, but if it were me I would take that down to 1 tsp, and focus on more zest and less juice. If you have a proper zesting rasp, you can get some good flavor out of an orange peel.

Answer (score 1):

The orange in orange beef is actually a dried tangerine peel.  It is called Chen pi in mandarin, which literally is "aged peel or skin".  陳皮.  This is typically used in Traditional Chinese medicine to help keep desolve fats and oils.  I think it is what makes the dish, and gives it that intense orange taste that orange juice doesn't have.